# Random distribution in Ruby

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, unit-testing, random, statistics

Below is a Ruby implementation of a random statistical event, based on a hash with the actual observed counts of outcomes.

I'd be interested in feedback in particular on what techniques I might use to avoid a loop-based accumulator in the `RandomEvent#predict!` method. I'm also very curious as well about any other suggestions on refactoring, patterns and performance that might be applicable here.

The statistics material itself might be somewhat beyond the scope of a review but I'd appreciate any thoughts on appropriate naming and more effective (deterministic) ways to test this.

**Spec**

```
include Statistics
describe RandomEvent do
  context 'when an event has only one outcome' do
    it 'always happens' do
      expect(RandomEvent.from_hash(always: 1).predict!).to eq(:always)
    end
  end

  context 'when the event has multiple outcomes' do
    let(:trials) { 10_000 }

    subject(:event) do
      RandomEvent.from_hash(heads: 51, tails: 49)
    end

    it 'should distribute them' do
      coinflips = trials.times.map { event.predict! }

      heads_variance = (coinflips.count(:heads) - trials/2).abs
      tails_variance = (coinflips.count(:tails) - trials/2).abs

      expected_variance = trials/10

      expect(heads_variance).to be < expected_variance
      expect(tails_variance).to be < expected_variance
    end
  end
end
```

**Implementation**

```
class RandomEvent
  def initialize
    @outcome_counts = {}
  end

  def add_outcome(outcome, count:)
    @outcome_counts[outcome] = count
  end

  def normalized_outcome_probabilities
    total_outcome_counts = @outcome_counts.values.reduce(&:+)
    @outcome_counts.inject({}) do |hash,(outcome,count)|
      hash[outcome] = count / total_outcome_counts.to_f
      hash
    end
  end

  def predict!
    acc = 0.0
    roll = rand
    selected_outcome = nil

    normalized_outcome_probabilities.each do |outcome, probability|
      acc += probability
      if acc > roll
        selected_outcome = outcome
        break
      end
    end

    selected_outcome
  end

  def self.from_hash(outcome_counts_hash)
    event = new
    outcome_counts_hash.each do |outcome, count|
      event.add_outcome(outcome, count: count)
    end
    event
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, it looks like `RandomEvent.from_hash` implements features of `initialize` method.

`acc` variable at `RandomEvent#predict` can be easily moved to `inject` iterator.

Code:

```
class RandomEvent
  def initialize(outcome_counts = {})
    @outcome_counts = outcome_counts
  end

  def add_outcome(outcome, count)
    @outcome_counts[outcome] = count
  end

  def normalized_outcome_probabilities
    total_outcome_counts = @outcome_counts.values.reduce(:+).to_f
    @outcome_counts.map { |outcome, count| [outcome, count / total_outcome_counts] }.to_h
  end

  def predict!
    roll = rand

    normalized_outcome_probabilities.inject(0.0) do |acc, (outcome, probability)|
      break outcome if (acc += probability) > roll
      acc
    end
  end
end
```

Now instead of `RandomEvent.from_hash(heads: 51, tails: 49)` you can write `RandomEvent.new(heads: 51, tails: 49)`

Comment: Hey, this is a great approach! Although I think we need to return `acc` in the body of the `inject` inside `predict!`?

Comment: Yes, definitely we need to return `acc`. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### Unit test

The statistical reasoning in this unit test looks sloppy to me:

> ```
> context 'when the event has multiple outcomes' do
>   let(:trials) { 10_000 }
>
>   subject(:event) do
>     RandomEvent.from_hash(heads: 51, tails: 49)
>   end
>
>   it 'should distribute them' do
>     coinflips = trials.times.map { event.predict! }
>
>     heads_variance = (coinflips.count(:heads) - trials/2).abs
>     tails_variance = (coinflips.count(:tails) - trials/2).abs
>
>     expected_variance = trials/10
>
>     expect(heads_variance).to be < expected_variance
>     expect(tails_variance).to be < expected_variance
>   end
> end
> ```

It looks like you are flipping a slightly biased coin, but for some reason you expect heads and tails each to be 50%.  Then, for 10000 trials, you're requiring the count of heads and tails to be within the 40%–60% range — a *very* generous band.

The head count should follow a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), namely \$B(n=10000, p=0.51)\$.  Applying [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_Bounds)

$$
\mathrm{Pr}(X \le k) \le e^{\frac{-2 (np - k)^2}{n}}
$$

for \$k = 4000\$ gives

$$
\mathrm{Pr}(X \le 4000) \le e^{-242} \approx 8 \times 10^{-106}
$$

The conclusion: for 10 coin flips, sure, the outcome can easily vary by 10%.  For 10000 coin flips, due to the [Law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) and the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), it basically *never* happens.  (It would be more likely that your computer is smashed by a meteor during the time it takes to run the test.)

### Implementation

The convention is to use the `!` suffix on methods that mutate the object.  Your `predict!` method doesn't really mutate the `RandomEvent` object, so I wouldn't name it with a `!`.<sup>1</sup>

Instead of doing the summation loop in `predict!`, it might be better to establish the cumulative thresholds in `add_outcome`, since that happens more rarely.

---

<sup>1</sup> Functional programming purists would note that the method consumes randomness from the pseudorandom number generator when `predict!` calls `rand`, and thus it does have a side-effect.  By Ruby standards, though, I wouldn't consider it mutation.  Besides, your `add_outcome` is much more of a mutation than `predict!`.

Comment: "The convention is to use the `!` suffix on methods that mutate the object." – No, the convention is to use the `!` suffix when you have a pair of identical named methods which do roughly the same thing to mark the "more surprising" variant. See, e.g. `Process::exit` vs. `Process::exit!` which has nothing to do with mutation and e.g. `String#replace` which *does* mutate but doesn't have a pair and thus doesn't get a `!` suffix.